# treating command-line args as integers in x86 AT&T Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, intel

This (Linux, AT&T, Intel) x86 program is meant to read in three arguments and store the biggest in %ebx as the exist status. When I pop the arguments into registers the resulting values seems to be bytes. How do I get the int value?

[edit -- thanks to harold's comment below I think the question is how do I use `atoi` to get the int value of the args.]

```
.section .text

.globl _start           

_start:
popl    %edi        # Get the number of arguments
popl    %eax        # Get the program name
popl    %ebx        # Get the first actual argument 
movl    (%ebx), %ebx    # get the actual value into the register (?) 
popl    %ecx        # ;
movl    (%ecx), %ecx
popl    %edx        #
movl    (%edx), %edx

bxcx:   
cmpl    %ebx,%ecx
jle     bxdx
movl    %ecx,%ebx
bxdx:
cmpl    %ebx,%edx
jle end
movl    %edx,%ebx

end:
movl    $1,%eax         
int $0x80
```

Comment: What int value? Are you looking for the equivalent of `atoi`?

Comment: The int value of the command-line args, after the program is run like `./a.out 5 6 7`  -- in this case the exit status should be 7. So if I need something like `atoi`, does that mean the values 5, 6 etc are read in as strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to call `atoi`, you'll need to link against libc. e.g.:

```
ld -lc foo.o
```

To actually make the call, you'll need to follow the cdecl calling convention:

1. Arguments to functions are passed on the stack with the leftmost argument being pushed last.
2. The return value of the function will be placed in the accumulator (%eax in this case).
3. Registers %ebp, %esi, %edi, and %ebx are preserved across calls, so you can use them for temporary storage.
4. Any other needed registers must be saved by the calling code (in the callee-saved registers above, on the stack before your arguments, or elsewhere in memory).

The signature of `atoi` is

```
int atoi(const char *nptr);
```

so to get the integer value of the first command line argument, we could do

```
.section .text

.globl _start           

_start:
popl    %edi        # Get the number of arguments
popl    %eax        # Get the program name
call    atoi        # Try to read the first argument as an integer and clobber %eax with the value
```

Comment: In order to get this working I needed to link it dynamically: `ld -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.2 -o test -lc test.o`